# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opencsv.CSVParser

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce, opencsv

I start using hadoop to run my code on aws. However, I got the error when using hadoop jar command:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opencsv.CSVParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at FlightsByCarrierMapper.map(FlightsByCarrierMapper.java:10)
    at FlightsByCarrierMapper.map(FlightsByCarrierMapper.java:5)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

I have included opencsv.jar in both CLASSPATH and HADOOP_CLASSPATH, but still fail. My hadoop version is 2.7.0 adn opecsv is 3.8. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: did you add job.setJarByClass(yourclass.class) ?

Comment: Please paste the complete command line for hadoop jar  as well as
the output of echo $CLASSPATH ; echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH